Let $(Y,d_Y) $ be a subspace of a metric space $(X,d).$ If $Y$ is complete then show that $Y$ is closed.
Let $(Y,d_Y) $ be a subspace of a metric space $(X,d).$ If $Y$ is complete then show that $Y$ is closed.
My solution goes like this:
Let $y$ be a limit point of $Y.$ This means $\exists$ a convergent sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n\neq y,\forall n\in \Bbb N$ satisfying $\lim y_n=y\in X.$ This means, $(y_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $X$ due to which it's a Cauchy sequence as well. This means, $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ since, $Y\subseteq X.$ But $Y$ is complete so, $(y_n)$ is convergent in $Y.$ Assuming, $(y_n)$ converges to $y'\in Y\subseteq X.$ Since the limit of the sequence in $X$ must be unique, so, $\lim y_n=y=y'.$ Hence, $y'=y\in Y.$
This proves that $Y$ is closed.

However, I think that something is a bit off with my solution. This is because, in the part where I wrote,

This means $\exists$ a convergent sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n\neq y,\forall n\in \Bbb N$ satisfying $\lim y_n=y\in X$

, I claimed that, $y\in X.$ But this might not be true in general. It might so happen that $y$ is in a metric space, say, $X'$ such that $X\subseteq X'$ and $y\in X'\setminus X.$
For example, if $Y=\Bbb Q, X=\Bbb Q\cup\{\sqrt 2\}$ then we find that, $1,1.7,1.73,1.732,...$ is a sequence in $Y$ that converges to $\sqrt 3$ but, it doesn't lie in $X.$ Instead $\sqrt 3$ lies in $\Bbb R$ which is a superset of $X.$ In situations like these, I think my solution goes wrong precisely due to this assumption that is, $y\in X.$
How can I fix this issue in my solution? If my solution is correct, then I would be interested to know, how is it so?

When  you are trying to prove a result about a metric space $X$ it makes no sense to go beyond $X$. $X$ is your universe.

@geetha290krm So, you're saying that the assumption: "Every convergent sequence in $X$ (which includes $Y$ obviously, as $Y\subseteq X$) converges at some point in $X$ as well" should be made in this case, right? In other words, we must assume that $X$ is closed as it seems.

Even if there's another metric space that $Y$ is contained in, the limit of a convergent sequence in $Y$ must be in $Y$ because $Y$ is complete. And since $Y \subseteq X$, that limit is also in $X$.

@RobertIsrael Thanks! That solved my problem. If you consider adding your comment as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

[Copied from comment as requested]
Even if there's another metric space that $Y$ is contained in, the limit of a convergent sequence in $Y$ must be in $Y$ because $Y$ is complete. And since $Y \subseteq X$, that limit is also in $X$.

Suppose $Y \subset X$ is complete. To prove that $Y$ is closed, it suffices to prove that if $(y_n)$ is a sequence of points of $Y$ which converges to $x \in X$, then $x \in Y$. So let $y_n$ be such a sequence. Since $y_n$ converges in $X$, it is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Therefore $(y_n)$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, so by completeness of $Y$, there exists some $x \in Y$ such that $y_n \to x$. Then by uniqueness of limits, we must have $y=x$, so $x \in Y$. Thus $Y$ is closed.
